# How can I skip cells in QTreeView?

Tags: c++, qt4, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

Conditions: C++/Qt 4.8.6. I have a `QTreeView` object, which is linked with a custom tree model. The leaves of the tree look like this row:

[module] [operation1] [operation2] [operation3] [operation4]

So, "module" is in 0 column, followed by "operation" cells. Each operation is in a separate column. I have a checkbox "Hide finished operations". How can I hide/skip finished operations in `QTreeView`? Each operation has corresponding boolean property `finished`. This property can be set to true at any time. I'd like to "squeeze" the row. I am aware about proxy models in Qt, but I can't figure out how to cope with my situation (though I've googled a lot). Should I use additional list of active operations (using shared pointers)?
Here is an example:

Before filtering:

[root]

--[group1]

----[module1] [finished operation1] [operation2] [operation3]

----[module2] [operation1] [operation2] [finished operation3] [operation4]

After filtering:

[root]

--[group1]

----[module1] [operation2] [operation3]

----[module2] [operation1] [operation2] [operation4]

Comment: Would calling QTreeView::setRowHidden() at the appropriate times get you the behavior you want?

Comment: Operations are laid horizontally, so hiding the whole row is redundant.

Comment: You can modify your datamodel class to return the appropriate results (for either mode) based on a boolean flag; then it's just a matter of forcing a re-render of the affected row(s) after you've changed the boolean flag's value.        I've had success manually forcing the update of a row via something like this:   viewport()->update(visualRect(indexOfFirstCellInRow) | visualRect(indexOfLastCellInRow)));   ... or you can just force a re-update of all rows view viewport()->update();